# Are flight attendants exempt from COVID-19 quarantine restrictions when leaving New York or entering Canada?

Tags: law, aviation, covid-19

Are the posts below true?

fathrowaway7. [2020 Mar 27 23:54 GMT](https://old.reddit.com/r/Coronavirus/comments/fq6829/an_american_airlines_flight_attendant_has_died/).

> I’m a flight attendant.
>
> We are still flying because we are considered “essential.” You heard about those orders to quarantine for 14 days after traveling from New York? We’re exempt. Canada requires a 14 day quarantine when traveling... We’re exempt from that too. We are exempt from EVERY SINGLE shelter in place or quarantine order.
>
> We have been told that if we’re confirmed to have been exposed to it, we can still work and not quarantine for 14 days, just to watch for symptoms. You heard that right. We can be exposed to coworkers and passengers with CONFIRMED cases and not be quarantined. We can still work, and possibly be spreading it around.
>
> We don’t even get pay protection for any work we miss if we get tested positive. We get pay protection ONLY if our positive case can be traced back to a positive case from a passenger.
>
> I have no doubt many of us have it and are asymptomatic and bringing it from city to city, killing people along the way.

Throwaway1099TFAYD. [Mar 27 2020 14:07 GMT](https://old.reddit.com/r/Coronavirus/comments/fq6829/an_american_airlines_flight_attendant_has_died/flpjwj8/)

> Can confirm everything he says. We were issued letters to get through national guard or police roadblocks if we have to. We are working, rain, shine, thunderstorms, snow, ice, of wind in order to spread it far and wide.
>
> And yes, we have to have a positive confirmed case and then test positive to get paid. They do take care of us and it isn't as bad as making $8/hr at Starbucks and getting left in the cold, but it still stinks.
>
> And yes, exempt from everything. In and out of Canada last week and got a random inspection, 1 total question which was "Did you pack your own bag?". That was with ADDITIONAL SCREENING.

Comment: This article suggests it is [true in Australia](https://www.smh.com.au/business/companies/qantas-crew-exempt-from-quarantine-have-tested-positive-for-covid-19-20200406-p54hhk.html)